# Учусь писать на С#, помогите найти ошибку в коде

Tags: c#

В общем, нашел приложение с обучением основ языка с#, сижу учу и тут есть следующая задачка:

**Вы учитель начальной школы, который объясняет своим ученикам умножение.
Вы собираетесь использовать умножение на 3 в качестве примера.
Вам дана программа, которая принимает число N в качестве входных данных. Напишите программу, которая будет выводить все числа от 1 до N, заменяя все числа кратные 3 на "*".**

Вводимые данные к примеру: 7
Ожидаемый выход: 12$45$7

//Вместо $ там *, сайт не пропускает//

То есть если N % 3 == 0 ставим "*"

Прикреплю написанный код, при его запуске выдает ошибку и отправляет меня куда подальше, перечитал уже все уроки которые прошел, ничего нового не нашел(

[image: Мой код]

Comment: Прямо так и пишет "Идите куда подальше"? `int x = 1` - дважды инициализируете переменную. Цикл `do...while` работать не будет, условие неверное (while переводится как "пока"). После `if` должен быть `else`, иначе вывод будет и звездочки, и кратного числа. И девайс скоро на зарядку надо...

Comment: Код вставлять надо текстом.

Comment: Научитесь определять разницу между `=` и `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0) Console.Write('*');
        else Console.Write(i);
    }
```

Comment: Автор все-таки хочет звёздочки :)

Comment: А как дать "звёздочку"? Это типо подтвердить правильность ответа? Вроде  дал, но это галочка зелёная

Comment: @user495353 да вроде галочки достаточно. Сам недавно начал пользоваться)